# How can you map a property to a specific column of another table using JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have two tables. One has the data I'm concerned about, "Thing".
Thing schema:

- thing_id
- name
- thing_type_id
- ...metadata (including created and modified dates)

'thing_type_id' is a foreign key for another table, which is basically acting as an enum.

ThingType schema:

- thing_type_id
- name
- ...metadata

I have created classes for both, and I can easily join the two using

`@ManyToOne() @JoinColumn(name = "thing_type_id") 
private ThingType thingType;`

to associate a ThingType object with each Thing. However, the only relevant field is ThingType.name.

What I want to do is reference the string directly, like

`@Column(table = "thing_type" name="name")
private String thingType;`

**Approaches I've tried**

- Using the `@SecondaryTable` annotation on the Thing class seems to only work for one-to-one mapping.
- `@JsonIgnore` on all irrelevant fields of ThingType leaves me with an object containing only one entry rather than just the value of that entry.
- Joining the whole object as above, @JsonIgnoring it, and create a getter to that field that somehow maps to the JSON output should work, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The third approach works.

`@JsonIgnore @ManyToOne() @JoinColumn(name = "thing_type_id") 
private ThingType thingType;`

`@JsonProperty("thingType")
String getThingType() { return this.thingType.getName(); }`